# Can't load a bean using SnakeYAML

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I got this error

> in 'reader', line 8, column 1:
>           time:
>           ^
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.Cfg$Time.()
>        in 'reader', line 9, column 3:
>             c: 5000
>             ^

when I've tried to load a `Cfg` bean:

```
Yaml yml = new Yaml();
Cfg cfg = yml.loadAs(file, Cfg.class);
```

Here is my bean class

```
public class Cfg {   
    private Time time;

    // getters & setters ommited

    public class Time {
        private Long c;
        private Long r;

        // getters & setters ommited
    }
}
```

And my YML file

```
---
time:
  c: 5000
  r: 5000
```

I use Java 6.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cfg must be a JavaBean (add setter and getter for time)
2. Time must be outside of Cfg, otherwise it has to have a link to Cfg
   instance (which is not configured in your YAML file)
3. The parser is called SnakeYAML

Comment: What do you mean by `link to Cfg instance`? It already has a link as the inner class always exists in the scope of outer class.

Comment: I mean Time is no JavaBean because it cannot be created via just empty constructor. It requires a Cfg instance. You can either instruct SnakeYAML how create Time instance or just put it out of Cfg.